# How can I limit the in put to 100 ?? Sorry if my coding style is bad , i just started

Tags: python, development-environment

```
def percent_finder ():   
    if range (1,100):
        a = int(input('Enter the mark: '))
        b = int(input('Enter the mark: '))
        c = int(input('Enter the mark: '))
        d = int(input('Enter the mark: '))
        e = int(input('Enter the mark: '))
        marks = a+b+c+d+e
        percent = marks/5
        return('You have ' + str(percent) + '%')
    else:
        return ('Wrong input !!! Enter marks again')
```

Comment: What do you think `if range (1,100):` does?

Comment: i thought it will add the limit

Comment: What led you to that (seriously incorrect) belief?